# Command Prompt - Shell, Terminal, Console?

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, cmd.exe, windows-shell

I know that `cmd.exe` is a *console program*. When you run that program, it opens your standard black and white rectangular window. Within that window, there is the *Command Line Interpreter* denoted by `>` (this is `$` in *NIX systems).

So if `cmd.exe` == "Command Prompt" == *Console Program*, does that make the window that opens a *Console*, *Console Window* or a *Terminal*?

**Bonus:**

Since a *shell* is a program that runs other program, `cmd.exe` must also be one. That said, what *shell* is it (i.e. *NIX has `bash` for example)? Is it just *Windows Shell*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What is `cmd.exe`?

`cmd` is a command-line interpreter, a program that accepts input, runs other programs and writes output.

> When you run that program, it opens your standard black and white rectangular window.

Not always. You can run a second `cmd.exe` in a currently open cmd window without opening a new command window.

> Does that make the window that opens a Console, Console Window or a Terminal?

The window is called a "Command Prompt", as indicated by it's title bar:

[image]

This particular command prompt is an Administrator command prompt.

> Since a shell is a program that runs other program, cmd.exe must also be one

If you want to use the word shell as a description then it is a cmd shell.

Answer (score 2):

I think of a terminal as an environment that accepts text input and provides text based output. It typically runs a shell which is an interpreter while the console is the physical terminal.

Put it this way: you start cmd.exe and run Powershell.

You are still at the same console, in the same terminal session. But your shell has changed ;)

[image]