# Why is the cmd.exe command line interpreter not called a shell?

Tags: windows, command-line, unix, shell, cmd.exe

I have been researching different command line interpreters and have noticed that the default Windows interpreter `cmd.exe` is not referred to as a shell on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_command-line_interpreters). Pretty much all of the command line interpreters of Unix-like systems are referred to as shells but not `cmd.exe` or most of the other interpreters for that matter.

Is there a reason for this or is "shell" just the nomenclature for interpreters belonging to Unix-like systems?

Comment: That's likely down to the opinion of whoever wrote that Wikipedia piece; Microsoft [refers to it as a shell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx) in some documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Command Prompt - Shell, Terminal, Console?](https://superuser.com/q/1229629/241386)

Comment: cmd.exe is in fact a shell. "Shell" is most commonly used in conjunction with Unix systems as you mention, where there is a wide variety of them, and thus it is worthwhile to speak of them generically as you don't know which one the user has/uses, but any interface in which you can provide (generic) input for execution is a shell. a Terminal provides character input to a command shell, but explorer.exe is a shell that takes gestural input as well as character data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Prompt - Shell, Terminal, Console?](https://superuser.com/questions/1229629/command-prompt-shell-terminal-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell is *main* user interface to operation system. In Windows this interface is GUI. It uses `explorer.exe` as "file manager",  creates "bottom menu", "folder window" and controls process of file opening: when you click on file it calls `ShellExecute` function.

So, "shell" in Windows is UI and "cmd" was only for some legacy or special commands. For many years Microsoft thought GUI is the best way to do anything.

It ~ 2006 they found that unix shells (bash, ksh, zsh) are very popular among sysadmins, so they invented *PowerShell*: .net based cmd substitution which is very cool especially if used with latest Powershell ISE.
It is called *shell* because its main purpose to become "first class citizen" for many sys-admin tasks. Any modern Microsoft server product has cmdlets so you can do almost anything from powershell (with out of MMC).

I do not know why they did not use word "Shell" for "command.com" in MS-DOS era.
It could be that they borrowed terminology from CP/M and called it "command processor".

Funny: there was a "DOS Shell" short-living GUI file manager for DOS. It was discontinued in 6.22 and most people used Norton Commander that time.

Comment: according to the [tag:shell] tag: "A shell is software that lets users interact with the operating system, usually by typing at a command-line."  [tag:windows-shell] [Windows Shell on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177(v=vs.85).aspx), [Windows Shell on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell)

Comment: A system can have many shells. cmd.exe, powershell.exe, and command.com, and explorer.exe are all examples of windows shells. The Op is simply incorrect that the command window is not called a shell.